# Drawing Dice with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program that plays the casino game craps, but instead of showing an integer output, irt shows the roll of the dice (like what the die would actually look like).  I have the actual gameplay down (I simulated the dice roll with `random.randint(1,6`, but the actual visual part is eluding me.  I've come across using the dictionary solution, but I'm not allowed to use that (What a load...)

The output should look something like the first one, ideally, but I keep getting the second one using the `join` command.

It should look like this....

```
+-----+       +------+
|     |       |      |
|     |       |      |
+-----+       +------+
```

But I keep getting this.

```
+------+
|      |
|      | 
+------++------+
|      |
|      |
+------+
```

And here's my code.  I know the list is hard to read, but it's the only way I'm allowed to do it.

```
list = ['+-------+' + '\n' + '|       |' + '\n' + '|   *   |' + '\n' + '|       |' +  '\n' + '+-------+' , '+-------+' + '\n' + '| *     |' + '\n' + '|       |' + '\n' + '|    *  |' +  '\n' + '+-------+' , '+-------+' + '\n' + '| *     |' + '\n' + '|   *   |' + '\n' + '|     * |' +  '\n' + '+-------+' , '+-------+' + '\n' + '|       |' + '\n' + '|   *   |' + '\n' + '|       |' +  '\n' + '+-------+']
sep = ''

x = sep.join(list[0:2])

print x
```

Answer (score 1):

I've enjoyed very much doing it. =)

```
base   = '+-------+         +-------+'
sep    = '         '
blank  = '|       |'
left   = '| *     |'
middle = '|   *   |'
right  = '|     * |'
both   = '| *   * |'

dice = [(blank, middle, blank),
        (left,  blank,  right),
        (left,  middle, right),
        (both,  blank,  both ),
        (both,  middle, both ),
        (both,  both,   both )]

def print_dice(a, b):
    print(base)
    print('\n'.join(a + sep + b for a, b in zip(dice[a-1], dice[b-1])))
    print(base)
```

Execution:

```
>>> print_dice(2, 5)
+-------+         +-------+
| *     |         | *   * |
|       |         |   *   |
|     * |         | *   * |
+-------+         +-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi-line strings.

```
 print("""
+-----+       +------+
|     |       |      |
|     |       |      |
+-----+       +------+
""")
```

And look up the `str.format()` method if you want to show the points on the cube.